# Private trait in public interface when blanket implement public trait to private trait

Tags: rust

Currently, I'm trying to blanket implement a public trait on any struct that implement a private trail, but i get compiler warning: `` private trait `mod_b::PrivateTrait` in public interface (error E0445) `` Is there anyway to fix this?

main.rs:

```
trait PublicTrait {}

mod mod_b
{
    use PublicTrait;
    trait PrivateTrait {}

    impl<T: PrivateTrait> PublicTrait for T {}
}

pub fn main ()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the `PrivateTrait` public

```rust
trait PublicTrait {}

mod mod_b {
    use crate::PublicTrait;
    pub trait PrivateTrait {}

    impl<T: PrivateTrait> PublicTrait for T {}
}

fn test<T: PublicTrait>(_: T){
    println!("public")
}

struct Private;
impl mod_b::PrivateTrait for Private {}

pub fn main() {
    test(Private);
}
```

Or to keep `PrivateTrait` private in `mod_b`

```rust
trait PublicTrait {}

mod mod_b {
    use crate::PublicTrait;
    trait PrivateTrait {}

    impl<T: PublicTrait> PrivateTrait for T {}
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to make PrivateTrait public, but I still want to implement PublicTrait on private type.

Comment: Then the only way is do it in reverse means implement PrivateTrait when T impllements PublicTrait. see issue https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34537

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this two ways: with a private `fn` outside of the `trait` in the same module (like you might do in JavaScript); and with a private `trait` and `pub trait` in the same module. In both cases, the solution involved implementing a generic and using the `Sized` constraint.

Private `fn`:

```rust
pub trait MyPublicTrait: Sized {
    fn get_msg(&self) -> &str { "Hello from" }

    fn do_something(&self) {
        do_something_impl(self);
    }
}

fn do_something_impl<T>(a: &T)
    where T: MyPublicTrait
{
    println!("{} private fn", a.get_msg());
}
```

Private `trait`:

```rust
trait MyPrivateTrait {
    fn do_something_impl(&self);
}

pub trait MyPublicTrait: Sized {
    fn get_msg(&self) -> &str { "Hello from" }

    fn do_something(&self) {
        self.do_something_impl();
    }
}

impl<T: MyPublicTrait> MyPrivateTrait for T {
    fn do_something_impl(&self) {
        println!("{} private trait", self.get_msg());
    }
}
```

The second one seemed confusing to me at first, because `MyPublicTrait` is using `do_something_impl` before it "knows" that `Self` will always implement `MyPrivateTrait`. But apparently the compiler knows what we're trying to say: that `do_something_impl` is always there for any `MyPublicTrait` because `MyPrivateTrait` is implemented for all `T: MyPublicTrait`. And vice versa, `get_msg` is available for `MyPrivateTrait` because any `T` will always be a `MyPublicTrait`.

And from the perspective of calling code outside of this module, the methods declared in `MyPrivateTrait` will never be available because you can't `use` a private `trait`.