# Why is this trait `impl` considered to leak a private trait?

Tags: rust, interface, private, public

The following code does not compile:

```rust
pub(crate) trait Private {}

pub trait Public {}

impl<T: Private> Public for T {}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0445]: private trait `Private` in public interface
 --> src/main.rs:7:1
  |
3 | pub(crate) trait Private {}
  | ------------------------ `Private` declared as private
...
7 | impl<T: Private> Public for T {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't leak private trait
```

I don't understand why the Private trait is considered leaked in this situation.

The [linked error explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0445) lists similar examples which do leak a private trait by using it in a trait bound. However, those examples are different because the trait bounds are something external crates can use.

For example, I can see why this is considered to leak the Private trait:

```rust
pub trait Public : Private {} // error: private trait in public interface
```

Here, external crates would be required to implement the Private trait (which they can't do) to implement the Public trait (which they can).

My first example is different in that external crates don't need to know anything about the Private trait – so I'm confused.

Where are the rules of leaking documented? What does leaking a private trait really mean?

Why does my example fail to compile? Is there a reason for guarding against such an `impl`?

Comment: meta: the [visibility] and [privacy] tags refer to other stuff, do we even have a tag for privacy in the sense used here?

Comment: To be able to conclude that your code does not actually leak a private trait, the compiler would need to understand that all `T`s the blanket implementation may apply to must be private types in the current crate, since otherwise they could not implement `Private`. I don't think the compiler is smart enough to perform this kind of proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Private trait in public interface when blanket implement public trait to private trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165161/private-trait-in-public-interface-when-blanket-implement-public-trait-to-private)

Comment: @SvenMarnach, I'm not sure what you mean... I can implement `Private` on an external struct like `String` too – but even then, how is anything being leaked? External crates still don't need to know anything about Private.

@eggyal, the linked answer gives a good workaround! But I still don't understand why this is an issue.

Comment: How could anyone discover that `Public` was thereby implemented for `String` (or indeed any public type) without the blanket implementation being publicly documented?  And how can the blanket implementation be publicly documented without such documentation leaking `Private`?

Answer (score 2):

As @eggyal explained in the comments, even though users of `Public` don't need to know anything about the `Private` trait, it is still leaked through the documentation, which must include the head of the `impl` block to communicate which types implement `Public`.

[image: Documentation for Public]

The workaround is to mark the `Private` trait as `pub`. It may still be hidden away in a private `mod` if you wish to keep it effectively private.

```rust
mod hidden {
    pub trait Private {}
}

pub(crate) use hidden::Private;

pub trait Public {}

impl<T: Private> Public for T {}
```